# Modal para varias imagenes

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una vista en MVC, a la que le llegan cinco imagenes. Para mostrarlas en el inicio, lo hago de esta manera:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen1 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                                        <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail modall" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen1)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                                    <div id="caption"></div>
                                </div>
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen2 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                                        <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail modall" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen2)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen3 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen3)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen4 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen4)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (Model.Imagenes.Imagen5 != null)
                            {
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="@Url.Content(Model.Imagenes.Imagen5)" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

Lo que quisiera, es que al hacerle clic, se agranden con JS, pero soy nuevo en frontend y me esta costando, logre que se agrande una cuando le hago clic, pero las otras no se agrandan cuando les hago clic a cada una de ellas. Alguien me podria mostrar como hacer un script para que esto pueda hacerse?. 
Gracias.

Comment: mírate este enlace de stackoverflow, aunque esté en ingles ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920534/enlarge-image-by-clicking-on-it-using-jquery

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Como escribi en la ultima parte, se como hacer que se agrande la imagen, pero no se como hacer para que todas tengan esta ufncionalidad. Uso lo que encontre en esta pagina https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Este trozo de código solo lo pones al case 1: tienes que agregarlo en todos los "case" para que te funcione en las 5 imágenes:

```
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                                <div id="caption"></div>
                            </div>
```